# Problems with implementing the functionality of web app using Spring and MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, web-applications

Im currently implementing the functionality of a web app (a symple task system) i have GUI made of multiple jsps which are using the bootstrap to look nice.
I went through many tutorials like "how to make jdbc app in spring" or "how to create simple web app using spring" ,but i cant figure how to make a web app that uses data from database using spring framework

To make it simple ..Imagine my MySQL database that has only one TABLE with 2 collumns one is ID and the secound is NAME.

What files(classes/xmls..etc) do i need to make and what should they contain to display the content of my database on a JSP.

Answer (score 0):

get a sample app from git hub, try this to start https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase

Or this for [domain driven desgin](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/)